# Angular: Material custom theme doesnt apply in input field

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2

I have the following material custom sass file:

```
@import '../node_modules/@angular/material/theming';
@include mat-core();

$app-primary: mat-palette($mat-red, 700, 800);
$app-accent: mat-palette($mat-red, 700, 800);
$app-warn: mat-palette($mat-red, 700, 800);
$app-theme: mat-light-theme($app-primary, $app-accent, $app-warn);

$app-input-primary: mat-palette($mat-red, 100, 200);
$app-input-accent: mat-palette($mat-red, 100, 200);
$app-input: mat-light-theme($app-input-primary, $app-input-accent);


@include mat-core-theme($app-theme);
@include mat-checkbox-theme($app-theme);
@include mat-radio-theme($app-theme);
@include mat-input-theme($app-theme);
```

The styles apply correctly to the checkbox and the radiobox, but do not apply in the input fields.

This is how I define the input field:

```
<md-form-field>
    <input mdInput placeholder="Card holder name">
</md-form-field>
```

The image below shows that the red style is applied to the radio, but the input loses the styles
[image]

If I change the broken-down includes with the one-liner `@include angular-material-theme($app-theme);` the red style works on the input, but my idea is to have a different palette for the input fields.

Comment: can you add a screenshot of the output ?

Comment: @Faisal I added an image.

Comment: Please see if your input styles are not being overridden with some other css

Comment: @Faisal, no they are not. :/. I dont have any custom styling for the inputs at this point

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Input field is part of the `<md-form-field>`. Add the following in your custom sass file:

```
@include mat-form-field-theme($app-theme); // Form-Field theme
@include mat-input-theme($app-theme);      // Input Theme
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that if you use the `@use` and `as mat` like: `@use '~@angular/material' as mat;`

Then you need to use

```
  @include mat.core-theme($default-theme);
  @include mat.button-theme($default-theme);
  @include mat.form-field-theme($default-theme); // Form-Field theme
  @include mat.input-theme($default-theme);      // Input Theme
  @include mat.checkbox-theme($default-theme);   // Checkbox Theme
```

Answer (score 0):

for **Angular 14**, we can apply the theme to all components.

```
@include mat.all-component-themes($app-theme);
```

Comment: The documentation recommends this if you are using all the components. Otherwise, you are just adding unused css to the client browser.